# How to remove undesired local task tabs

Tags: 8

I have a node type 'faq'. For node type 'faq' I need to remove the tab 'node clone'.

For that I have done the following codes.
In node_clone.routing.yml I have the following code

```
      
node_clone.prepopulate_node:  
  path: '/node/{node}/clone/prepopulate'  
  defaults:  
    _title: 'Clone content'  
    _controller: 'node_clone.form_controller:getContentResult'  
  requirements:  
    _custom_access: 'node_clone.form_controller:access'  
    #_node_add_access: 'node:{node_type}'  
    node: '\d+'  
  options:  
    _node_operation_route: TRUE  
    parameters:  
      node:  
        type: 'entity:node'
```

In my controller file

```
public function access(AccountInterface $account, NodeInterface $node) {

      $node_type = ($node->getType());
      if($node_type=="faq")
      {
          $access = new AccessResultForbidden();

      }

    if ($account->hasPermission('clone node') || ($node->uid->value === $account->id() && $account->hasPermission('clone own nodes'))) {
      $access = new AccessResultAllowed();
    }

    else {
      $access = new AccessResultForbidden();
    }
    $access->addCacheableDependency($node);
    $access->cachePerPermissions();
    if ($access->isAllowed()) {
      $access = $access->andIf($node->access('view', $account, TRUE));
    }
    if ($access->isAllowed()) {
      $node_type = NodeType::load($node->getType());
      $access = $access->andIf($this->nodeAddAccessCheck->access($account, $node_type));
    }
    return $access;
  }
```

Please help me to find out what's wrong with my code? Is this enough or I should do something else?

Answer (score 14):

To completely remove the tab from all pages you can use [hook_local_tasks_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_local_tasks_alter/8.4.x).

```
function mymodule_local_tasks_alter(&$local_tasks) {
  unset($local_tasks['local_task_to_remove']);
}
```

Where `local_task_to_remove` is the tab you want to remove.

To have it removed from some pages you could use [hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/8.4.x) instead. Something like:

```
function mymodule_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name) {
  $routes = ['entity.entity_view_display.node.default', ...]; // put other routes in place of '...'
  if (in_array($route_name, $routes)) {
    unset($data['tabs'][0]['local_task_to_remove']); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Since 8.5, `hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()` gives you **&$cacheability** metadata as a third-parameter, so it's a good idea to check you have the correct [cache contexts](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$access` variable is overwritten with the original Node Clone logic that looks at whether the user has the permission. Hence, it will never return an `AccessResultForbidden` object on the `faq` content type and deny access to the route.

You should avoid hacking the Node Clone module, the module has incomplete feature to add/exclude node types (the project is still in the dev phase). Looking at the project, it looks like all that's needed is update the setting form (to update the per-node type settings) and `_custom_access` function to read in those settings. You should utilize that and create a patch for the project if you're going down that that route.

However, if you're insistent on overriding Node Clone's route permissions, you can [override it's access permission](https://www.drupal.org/node/2187643) using a `RouteSubscriber`:

```
  // see link for an example RouteSubscriber.php & example.services.yml

  /**
   * Inside your module's RouteSubscriber::alterRoutes method
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('node_clone.prepopulate_node')) {
      $route->setRequirement('_custom_access', '\Drupal\example\Routing\RouteSubscriber::nodeCloneAccessOverride');
    }
  }

  /**
   * An example override _custom_access override.
   */
  public static function nodeCloneAccessOverride(AccountInterface $account, NodeInterface $node) {
    if ($node->getType() == 'faq') {
      return new AccessResultForbidden();
    }
    else {
      return new AccessResultAllowed();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this - there aren't a lot of examples of overriding permissions in another module where you *also* need to do so based on user role/permissions. (Note, if you first attempt to use `\Drupal::currentUser()` directly within alterRoutes, it doesn't throw an error, it'll return an anonymous user regardless of who's actually logged in.)

Answer (score -1):

If using drupal 8/9 you can enable or disable them from the block layout. The blocks for these are:

- Tabs
- Primary Tabs
- Secondary Tabs

Also make sure that the block region you assign to is being outputted in your twig template.

e.g.  for the header region it is something like {{ page.header }}